# Undefined reference to error is showing an extra parameter for my function, GTKMM C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, gtkmm, allocator

I am writing a snakes and ladders game and I defined a function called draw_snake as follows:

```
void draw_snake(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr, 
                std::pair<int,int> snake, 
                std::vector< std::pair<int,int> > boardcoords);
```

When I make the call to this function I do it as follows:

```
pair<int, int> snake = make_pair(100,1);
draw_snake(cr, snake, boardcoords);
```

`boardcoords` is a vector of `pair<int,int>`. The error message is saying that I have a fourth parameter when i call the function. The error message is this:

```
myarea.cc:(.text+0x7db): undefined reference to `MyArea::draw_snake(Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> const&, std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >)'
```

Where is it getting this allocator from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misreading the error.  The function has three parameters.

```
undefined reference to `MyArea::draw_snake(
         Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> const&,
         std::pair<int, int>,
         std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >
//                  ^ The vector's parameters are contained in these brackets  ^
         )
```

[`std::vector` has a default "allocator" parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  It exists even when you don't specify it.

So the error you're getting is that the exact function you declared is not defined.